# Is $H^{1}(R;H^1(R^n))=H^1(R^{n+1})$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Is $H^{1}(R;H^1(R^n))=H^1(R^{n+1})$,

where

$H^1(R;H^1(R^n))=\{f\colon R\to H^1(R^n)\colon \int \|f(t,\cdot)\|_{H^1}^2\,dt <\infty \quad \text{and} \int \|f'(t,\cdot)\|_{H^1}^2\,dt <\infty \}$

(and $g=f'\Leftrightarrow \int f(t,\cdot)\phi'(t)\,dt=-\int g(t,\cdot)\phi(t)\,dt \quad \forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(R,R)$)

Comment: there is some confusion with $x$ and $t$. As to the statement, you could try checking this in the Fourier domain (ie verify that the norms are equivalent for sufficiently smooth functions on $R^{n+1}$)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so for $n=1$ I get $\mathcal{F}(f)(x,t)x \,\in L^2(R^2)$ and $\mathcal{F}(f)(x,t)xt \,\in L^2(R^2)$ for $f\in H^1(H^1)$ smooth enough, but not $\mathcal{F}(f)(x,t)t\,\in L^2$ (which holds for $H^1(R^{n+1})$). Am I done yet? ;) (i.e. is my hypothesis wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Indeed, $f\in H^1(R^{n+1})\Leftrightarrow f$ and all of its first derivatives (in the sense of distributions) are in $L^2$. But if $f\in H^1(R,H^1(R^n))$, then necessarily $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t\partial x_j}$ also lie in $L^2$, which is not the case for a general function in $H^1(R^{n+1})$.

Comment: @Bananach: one could therefore expect $L^2(R; H^1(R^n)) \cap H^1(R; L^2(R^n)) = H^1(R^{n+1})$